# Jolt converts JSON array to JSON Object automatically

Tags: json, jolt

I have a json which consists a json array 'attrs'. This array contains name/value pairs so the number of objects inside it is dynamic. I know 2 name/value pairs that will always be present and i'm currently using jolt to extract them and bring them to the outermost level.
During this process, I'm seeing three scenarios

**Jolt Spec** used :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "attrs": {
          "*": {
            "name": {
              "*": {
                "@2": "[&5].&4"
              },
              "orderType": {
                "@(2,value)": "[&5].&1"
              },
              "paymentType": {
                "@(2,value)": "[&5].&1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Scenario 1: All name/value pairs in 'attrs' were the ones I was expecting, therefor after using jolt nothing was left inside this 'attrs' and in the transformed json, this 'attrs' was not present. This was expected.

**Input JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "attrs": [
      {
        "name": "orderType",
        "value": "PROVPN"
      },
      {
        "name": "paymentType",
        "value": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "orderType": "PROVPN",
    "paymentType": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod"
  }
]
```

**Scenario 2** : Along with the name/value pairs I was expecting, there was ONE extra name/value pair. After transformation, the expected name/value pairs are in the outermost level but the 'attrs' is transformed as an OBJECT. This was not expected, I was expecting 'attrs' to remain an array.

**Input JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "attrs": [
      {
        "name": "orderType",
        "value": "PROVPN"
      },
      {
        "name": "paymentType",
        "value": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod"
      },
      {
        "name": "deliveryType",
        "value": "CRM"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "orderType": "PROVPN",
    "paymentType": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod",
    "attrs": {
      "name": "deliveryType",
      "value": "CRM"
    }
  }
]
```

**Scenario 3** : Along with the name/value pairs I was expecting, there were multiple extra name/value pair. After transformation, the expected name/value pairs are in the outermost level but the 'attrs' is transformed as an ARRAY. This was expected.

**Input JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "attrs": [
      {
        "name": "orderType",
        "value": "PROVPN"
      },
      {
        "name": "paymentType",
        "value": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod"
      },
      {
        "name": "deliveryType",
        "value": "CRM"
      },
      {
        "name": "deliveryAddress",
        "value": "aBC"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Output JSON** :

```json
[
  {
    "requestedStartDate": null,
    "cuDetails": [
      {
        "role": "Customer",
        "value": "ABX"
      },
      {
        "role": "ABC",
        "value": "ABC"
      }
    ],
    "notes": null,
    "orderType": "PROVPN",
    "paymentType": "Upgrade/Downgrade/ChangeContractPeriod",
    "attrs": [
      {
        "name": "deliveryType",
        "value": "CRM"
      },
      {
        "name": "deliveryAddress",
        "value": "aBC"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Expected Output in Scenario 2 & 3** : In case that **`attrs`** JSON array is displayed, i want it to be displayed as an *array* not an *object* .

Answer (score 0):

In any case the following spec will return an **array** for extra **`attrs`** by adding square brackets `[]` :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "attrs": {
          "*": {
            "name": {
              "*": { // else case for "name" matches
                "@2": "[&5].&4[]"
              },
              "orderType|paymentType": {
                "@2,value": "[&5].&1"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```